# Hide Div if no image in the loop

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Im looking to create a condition in wordpress loop. if no image then image box (.thumbHome{display:none})

this is in my function.php

```
function getThumbImages($postId) {
$iPostID = get_the_ID();
$arrImages =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' .   $iPostID );
if($arrImages) {
    $arrKeys = array_keys($arrImages);
    $iNum = $arrKeys[0];
    $sThumbUrl = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($iNum, $something);
    $sImgString =  '<img src="' . $sThumbUrl . '" alt="thumb Image" title="thumb Image" />';
echo $sImgString;}
else {
echo '<script language="javascript">noImage()</script>';
}
}
```

And my javascript:

```
window.onload = noImage();
 function noImage(){
document.getElementByClassName('.thumbHome').css.display = 'none';
}
```

I tried:

```
window.onload = noImage();
function noImage(){
$('.thumbHome').addClass('hide');
}
```

RESULT: class hide added to all loop

I cant figure it another way, since im still new in coding.

thx

Comment: You could always default the box to be hidden and simply emit an override css after the loop completes if there were actually any images. You've got all the information server-side already, might as well make use of it. Of course, people with javascript won't see any pictures, but that's their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you don't want to call these functions on `window.onload`.  That's going to immediately set all class instances of `.thumbHome` to hidden without any conditions.

Here's a very easy way to fix this issue. There are probably more intricate ways, but this works well.

In your main loop, add an unique id to each `.thumbHome` div based on the image id.  So like:

```
echo '<div class="thumbHome" id="thumb-' . $iNum . '"> ... </div>';
// or you could you use the post ID, doesn't matter, as long as you are consistent
```

Then your else conditional (for whether there's a thumbnail) could be changed to:

```
else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">noImage("#thumb-' . $iNum . '")</script>';
}
```

and your js function could be:

```
function noImage(var){
    $(var).hide();
}
```

This is not necessary the best way to do this, it's just the best way with the situtation you find yourself in now.

Comment: It still showing an empty box.  here is the screenshot. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2527203/Screen%20shot%202011-01-14%20at%2014%20January%202011%3E%3E10.36.47%20AM.png